# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on classloader from external jar on a repo

Tags: java, reflection, classloader, urlclassloader

I am trying to load the external jar and create a structure of all the classes from that jar.

Currently, the jar is using a dependency on a different location on the repo.

Accessed jar is located at someurl/com/xyz/mystuff2.jar
Accessed jar mystuff1.jar is dependent on  someurl/com/abc/mystuff1.jar.

I tried the following.

```
try {
    u = new URL("jar", "", this.url /* Some url*/+ "!/");

    URL[] urls = { u };             
    URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = this.jarFile.entries();

    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

        /* Soft checks to make sure it is not pulling an inner class
         */

        if (entry.isDirectory() || !entry.getName().endsWith(".class")
                && !entry.getName().contains("$")) {
            continue;
        }

        String className = entry.getName().substring(0,
                entry.getName().length() - 6);
        className = className.replace('/', '.');
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Class<?> c = cl.loadClass(className); /*It errors while   
                loading a class that are extending classes from mystuff.jar*/

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("ERROR: Classes were not loaded properly "
                    + e.getMessage());

        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
                logger.error("ERROR: Classes definition was not found "
                        + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {             
    logger.error("ERROR : There is an issue while accessing the 
        URL"+ e.getMessage());      
}
```

I am certainly missing a point here, since the jar is already compile and deployed, it should have the bindings from mystuff1 already. Also, given that the extended classes are abstract, what could be an alternative to get the classes loaded or know about them.

My goal is to able to retrieve all the classes,  those that extends my BaseClass.class, through reflection and perform create some meaningful structure.

Edit:

Used aliases.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/myorg/xyz/core/BaseClass
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:789)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.myorg.xyz.gotto.go.repomanager.MavenRepoManager.loadClassesFromJar(MavenRepoManager.java:97)
    at com.myorg.xyz.gotto.go.RepoManagerTest.testRepoManager(RepoManagerTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myorg.xyz.core.BaseClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:789)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @NikolayKasapov : Not sure about the issue, can this be security issue? or do I have to load the classes from the dependent jars separately?

Comment: I assume that the error occurred because of !entry.getName().contains("$").
The only reason to get NoClassDefFoundError when using ClassLoader is that the name of the class (in your case className variable) is not equal to the binary name of the class.

Comment: If they are not loaded you have to load them!!!

Comment: if that is the case, do we have to load all the files from the dependent jars separately? or is there an easier way to retrieve it straightforward?

Comment: look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass(java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20int,%20int,%20java.security.ProtectionDomain). 
As I suggested the difference between className and binary class name are causing the issue. May be it will be better if you start using OSGi.